# Ограничение по отправке формы на php

Tags: forms, php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Нужно сделать ограничение по количеству отправки формы в минуту. Допустим, форму можно отправить 3 раза в 1 минуту, 30 сек. Юзал гугл, но путнего не нашел. Как я понял, реализовывается это с помощью $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отслеживать кол-во отправок формы можно с помощью сессии.
Как только зашел пользователь, запускаете сессию. После первой отправки формы также в сессии фиксируем время и кол-во успешных отравок. При последующих попытках сверяем время последней отправки формы и кол-во успешных отправок, если оно в нужных рамках, отправляем форму, если нет, выводим соотв. уведомление.

Comment: @Зоркий перезапустил браузер - убил сессии. Как вариант даза банных.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю так:

1. зашел пользователь, нажал кнопку, выводим ему сообщение все успешно;
2. записываем в БД, информацию о пользователе (Индивидуальный номер пользователя, дату, IP,   ну и так далее);
3. а при нажатии кнопки проверяете ID, IP, и Дату.

Comment: Так все таки лучше всего использовать базы данных? 
Все таки лишние запросы.
С помощью баз данным можно так: 1) Человек отправляет форму, заносим в таблицу и указываем время заноса. 2) Сверяем по времени последние его сообщения. (Но мне этот вариант кажется плохим и не удобным).
А вот с помощью печенья, сессий, "глобальных переменным" как-нибудь это реализовывается?

Comment: Вот ты говоришь куки, и сессии, да можно использовать куки и сессии, но предположим такую ситуацию:

1. зашел, нажал

2. захотел нажать еще раз (очистил куки, и сессию) нажал второй раз, и так далее

если это не важно, то можно остановится на сессиях или куках

Comment: В принципе ты прав. Но все же хотелось бы найти альтернативу базам данных.

Comment: можешь в файл писать, если не хочешь в базу

Comment: Тем более не вариант.